# Evaluate the following limit using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x\to 12^+}\frac{1}{x-12}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-12}}$

I don't understand the different indeterminate forms such as $\infty *0$ and the methods used to rewrite them so L'Hopitals is applicable. 
How would I go about rewriting this so L'Hopital's rule is applicable?

Comment: $\frac 0\infty$ is by no means indeterminate: it's $0$. I don't see how this relates to the rest, but you might want to know that nevertheless.

Comment: Make a single fraction out of it: put it over a common denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1-\sqrt{x-12}\sim1$ as $x\to12^+$, @BrianM.Scott's advice gives$$\lim_{x\to12^+}\frac{1-\sqrt{x-12}}{x-12}=\lim_{x\to12^+}\frac{1}{x-12}=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $y^2=x-12 >0$, and consider lim $y \rightarrow 0^+$.

Let $0<y <1/2$:

$\dfrac{1}{y^2}-\dfrac{1}{y}=$

$\dfrac{1-y}{y^2} \gt \left (\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\dfrac{1}{y^2}>  \left (\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\dfrac{1}{y}$.

What is $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{1}{y}$?